# How to match a regex pattern for multiple files under a directory in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I wrote a script to match a pattern and return a statement for a file

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = '/home/Sidtest/sid.txt';
open my $info , $file or die " Couldn't open the $file:$!";
while( my $line = <$info>) {
    if ($line =~ m/^#LoadModule ssl_module/) {
        print "FileName =",$file,"  Status = Failed \n";
    }
    elsif ($line =~ m/^LoadModule ssl_module/) {
        print "FileName =",$file,"  Status = Passed \n";
    }
}
close $info;
```

So now I am trying to modify this script to work for multiple files under the same directory. I haven't been able to do that successfully. Can anyone please help in how I can make it work for any number of files in a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will read every file in `./directory` and foreach file, print out each line.

The print statement can be altered to `print if /match/`, or whatever you want:

```
my @dir = <directory/*>;

foreach my $file (@dir){
    open my $input, '<', $file;
        while (<$input>){
        print "PASS: $_\n" if m/^#LoadModule ssl_module/;
        [...]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `@ARGV` contains a list of arguments sent to the script when started. Loop through `@ARGV` and call the script with the files you want to process:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my $file (@ARGV) {
    open my $info , $file or die " Couldn't open the $file:$!";
    while( my $line = <$info>) {
        if ($line =~ m/^#LoadModule ssl_module/) {
            print "FileName =",$file,"  Status = Failed \n";
        }
        elsif ($line =~ m/^LoadModule ssl_module/) {
            print "FileName =",$file,"  Status = Passed \n";
        }
    }
    close $info;
}

# process all files *.txt in your dir: ./myscript.pl /home/Sidtest/*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Check perldoc perlrun, and look at the -p and -n parameters.  Essentially, they treat your script as if it were the contents of a loop over stdin, where stdin is generated by iterating through the files supplied on the command line.  The name of the file currently-being-processed can be accessed using the $ARGV variable.

So, you might go for an approach where your whole script looks more like this, using the -n param, where $_ contains the current line.:

```
if ( m/^#LoadModule ssl_module/) {
   print "FileName =",$ARGV"  Status = Failed \n";
} elsif (m/^LoadModule ssl_module/) {
   print "FileName =",$ARGV,"  Status = Passed \n";
}
```

Comment: Did you **really** try it?